# Keeping unused levels in ggplot2 bar plot does not work properly

Tags: r, ggplot2, levels, drop, stacked-bar-chart

R version 4.3.1
library(ggplot2) version 3.4.2

I want to use ggplot2 bar charts to display the percentage frequency of a particular concentration class.
I have five concentration classes (=c1 with the options "1_", "2_", "3_", "4_", "5_") for which an event can occur "Early" (=c2 dichotomous with "yes" or "no") or "Late" (=c3 dichotomous with "yes" or "no").

To prevent bars from dropping in the diagram, I have set "scale_x_discrete (drop = FALSE)" in the ggplot.

If an event occurs in one, three, four or all five concentration classes, bar charts are drawn as I imagined them: no bar is drawn for the concentrations for which no event occurred, but all five concentration classes are displayed on the x-axis.

If an event occurs in only two concentration classes, then instead of the two thin bars at the respective concentrations, adjacent bold bars are drawn.

What is the reason for this problem and how can I solve it?
Thank you very much in advance for any advice.

This is the code I used:

```
# build data.frame
c1 <- c("1_", "1_", "2_", "2_", "3_", "4_", "4_", "4_", "5_", "5_")
c2 <- c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no")
c3 <- c("no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes") # for five bars
c3 <- c("no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes") # for four bars
c3 <- c("no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes") # for three bars
c3 <- c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes") # for two bars --> THIS is where the error occurs
c3 <- c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no") # for one bars

dataf <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3)
dataf

# compilation of data + addition of column with event status + reduction of table to relevant columns
bp11 <- dataf %>% mutate(c.Compilation = case_when(c2 == "yes" ~ "EarlyEvent",
                                                   c3 == "yes" ~ "LateEvent")) %>%
  select(c1, c.Compilation)
bp11

# insert number (n) and percentage share (prop)
bp22 <- bp11 %>% group_by(c1) %>% count(c.Compilation) %>% mutate(prop = n / sum(n) * 100)

# removal of NA
bp33 <- bp22[complete.cases(bp22$c.Compilation), ]

# specify factor level order "Groups"
bp33$c.Compilation = factor(bp33$c.Compilation, levels = c("LateEvent", "EarlyEvent"))

# specify factor level order "Concentration"
bp33$c1 = factor(bp33$c1, levels = c("1_", "2_", "3_", "4_", "5_"))

# calculate n of each concentration group
calcN <- table(bp11$c1)
calcN

# draw stacked barplot
ggplot(bp33,
       aes(x = c1, y = prop, fill = c.Compilation)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack") +
  labs(x = "Concentration (mg/L)",
       y = "Event (%)",
       fill = "Groups",
       title = "Css") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position = c(.18, .84)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("1_", "2_", "3_", "4_", "5_"),
                   drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limit = c(-1, 101), breaks = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100)) +
  annotate("text", x = c(0.9, 1.15), y = -1, label = c("n = ", calcN[c("1_")]), size = 5) +  
  annotate("text", x = c(1.9, 2.15), y = -1, label = c("n = ", calcN[c("2_")]), size = 5) +
  annotate("text", x = c(2.9, 3.15), y = -1, label = c("n = ", calcN[c("3_")]), size = 5) +
  annotate("text", x = c(3.9, 4.15), y = -1, label = c("n = ", calcN[c("4_")]), size = 5) +
  annotate("text", x = c(4.9, 5.15), y = -1, label = c("n = ", calcN[c("5_")]), size = 5) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.6, end = 0)
```

This is the result I get when I run the code:

[Five bars in the bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4thz0.png)

[Four bars in the bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWdYp.png)

[Three bars in the bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRAD7.png)

[Two bars in the bar chart, this is where the error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTN37.png)

[One bar in the bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i80Mu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me (which after some testing occurs only with `stat="identity"` and when there are no adjacent categories).

**NOTE**: The issue was already reported and is fixed in the development version of ggplot2. (see below).

A workaround would be to manually complete your dataset using e.g. `tidyr::complete`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

bp33_complete <- bp33 |>
  ungroup() |>
  complete(c1, c.Compilation, fill = list(prop = 0))

ggplot(
  bp33_complete,
  aes(x = c1, y = prop, fill = c.Compilation)
) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = c("1_", "2_", "3_", "4_", "5_"),
    drop = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(5, 100, 5),
    limits = c(-1, 101)
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Concentration (mg/L)",
    y = "Event (%)",
    fill = "Groups",
    title = "Css"
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = c(.18, .84)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = after_stat(paste0("n = ", count)),
      y = after_stat(-1),
      fill = NULL
    ),
    data = bp11,
    stat = "count",
    size = 5
  ) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.6, end = 0)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
c1 <- c("1_", "1_", "2_", "2_", "3_", "4_", "4_", "4_", "5_", "5_")
c2 <- c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no")
# for two bars --> THIS is where the error occurs
c3 <- c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes") 

dataf <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3)
```

**EDIT** Here is a refactored code which uses only one dataset, keeps the `NA`s (but drops them for the geom_col) and uses `geom_text` with `stat="summary"` to compute the `n=` which should also work for cases with `n=0`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

# Drop one c1 category
dataf <- filter(dataf, c1 != "4_")

bp33 <- dataf %>%
  mutate(c.Compilation = case_when(
    c2 == "yes" ~ "EarlyEvent",
    c3 == "yes" ~ "LateEvent"
  )) %>%
  count(c1, c.Compilation) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n) * 100, .by = c1) |>
  mutate(
    c.Compilation = factor(c.Compilation,
      levels = c("LateEvent", "EarlyEvent")
    ),
    c1 = factor(c1,
      levels = c("1_", "2_", "3_", "4_", "5_")
    )
  ) |>
  complete(c1, c.Compilation, fill = list(prop = 0, n = 0))

ggplot(
  bp33,
  aes(x = c1, y = prop)
) +
  geom_col(
    data = ~ filter(.x, !is.na(c.Compilation)),
    aes(fill = c.Compilation)
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = c("1_", "2_", "3_", "4_", "5_"),
    drop = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(5, 100, 5),
    limits = c(-1, 101)
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Concentration (mg/L)",
    y = "Event (%)",
    fill = "Groups",
    title = "Css"
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = c(.18, .84)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = after_stat(paste0("n = ", y)),
      y = stage(n, after_stat = -1),
      fill = NULL,
      group = c1
    ),
    stat = "summary",
    fun = sum,
    size = 5
  ) +
  scale_fill_grey(
    start = 0.6, end = 0
  )
```

[image]

**Update** The issue was already reported [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5400) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5396) and seems to be fixed in the development version of ggplot2:

Using `ggplot2 3.4.4`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.4.4'

dat <- data.frame(
  x = factor(c("A", "E"), levels = LETTERS[1:5])
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y = 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + # or geom_col
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Using the development version:

```r
library(ggplot2)

packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.4.4.9000'

dat <- data.frame(
  x = factor(c("A", "E"), levels = LETTERS[1:5])
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y = 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + # or geom_col
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful tips! I have been able to adopt them for my actual data set. Now I am still facing the problem that when using the "workaround" (with the modified code), no bar labels are displayed if there is no number (n=0) in a concentration group. I'm sure just some small change in the "geom_text" command is needed to fix this problem, but I can't find the right hints or I am probably searching for the wrong terms. How can I proceed to get a count (even at n=0) displayed beneath each column?

Comment: I just made an edit to account for the case `n=0`. Basically I refactored your code to use only one dataset.